# Subgroups of PSL(2,R): criteria for discreteness

Tags: group-theory, riemann-surfaces

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ generated by a set of matrices $\mathcal M=(M_i)_{i\in I}$.

Is there an effective  criterion on $\mathcal M$ ensuring that $G$ is discrete?

Comment: try to googlize "discreteness criterion group SL(2,C)". you may be also interested in the so called schottky groups (see wikipedia)

Comment: you may also want to see this mathoverflow post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96469/matrices-generating-non-discrete-subgroups-of-sl2-r

Answer (score 1):

The question can be reduced to the case that $G$ is $2$-generated. In this case there is an effective algorithm to decide discreteness by Jane Gilman, [The non-Euclidean Euclidean algorithm](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1207.1062.pdf). In particular see Theorem $3.1$ and the following.

Comment: very nice reference!